# PrefixQuery case sensitive?

Tags: lucene

I have an **untokenized field** in index file. I'm using **PrefixQuery** to get the values. I'm using this for auto suggesting(When i give the keyword it will start suggesting the relevant data).

**For Example:**
The field name is 'Country'. It has the list of countries as values like Australia, America, India, Singapore, South Africa, New Zealand...(**With Title Case**)

When I give the query string(input) as **'a'**, It is not suggesting any countries.. Instead if i give **'A'** means it is suggesting Australia, America...

How can I overcome this Case problem? What is wrong with this??

Your help is appreciated...

Thanks

Perumal A S

Comment: It should be case insensitive by default..http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Are_Wildcard.2C_Prefix.2C_and_Fuzzy_queries_case_sensitive.3F

Answer (score 1):

From http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Are_Wildcard.2C_Prefix.2C_and_Fuzzy_queries_case_sensitive.3F

> Are Wildcard, Prefix, and Fuzzy queries case sensitive?
>
> No, not by default. Unlike other types
>   of Lucene queries, Wildcard, Prefix,
>   and Fuzzy queries are not passed
>   through the Analyzer, which is the
>   component that performs operations
>   such as stemming and lowercasing. The
>   reason for skipping the Analyzer is
>   that if you were searching for "dogs*"
>   you would not want "dogs" first
>   stemmed to "dog", since that would
>   then match "dog*", which is not the
>   intended query. These queries are
>   case-insensitive anyway because
>   QueryParser makes them lowercase. This
>   behavior can be changed using the
>   setLowercaseExpandedTerms(boolean)
>   method.

Comment: Yes... You are right.. But how to get rid of this.. I wasted a whole day by searching why it is not suggested... Can you give me a solution for this....
I mean, when I enter 'a', it should suggest 'Australia' without case sensitive... Please....

Comment: Try using a lower case filter when indexing and then setLowercaseExpandedTerms(true) during query time.